# mysql additional condition after INNER JOIN, ON

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I have this query right now

```
global $wpdb;
$interval = "1 WEEK";
$now = current_time('mysql');
$top4=$wpdb->get_results('SELECT ID, post_title, post_name from `'.$wpdb->prefix.'popularpostssummary`       
INNER JOIN `'.$wpdb->prefix.'posts` ON `postid`=`ID` 
ORDER BY `pageviews` DESC 
LIMIT 4;', ARRAY_A);
```

And I want to add the following conditions, what's the proper way of adding them in the code?

```
WHERE post_type = post
AND last_viewed > DATE_SUB('{$now}', INTERVAL {$interval})
```

post_type is under '.$wpdb->prefix.'posts
`while last_viewed is under '.$wpdb->prefix.'popularpostssummary`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```php
global $wpdb;
$interval = "1 WEEK";
$now = current_time('mysql');
$sql = 
    'SELECT p.ID, p.post_title, p.post_name
     FROM `' . $wpdb->prefix . 'popularpostssummary` AS pps
         INNER JOIN `' . $wpdb->prefix . 'posts` AS p ON pps.`postid`= p.`ID`
     WHERE p.post_type = "post"
         AND pps.last_viewed > DATE_SUB("' . $now . '", INTERVAL ' . $interval . ')
     ORDER BY pps.`pageviews` DESC 
     LIMIT 4;';
echo $sql; exit;
$top4 = $wpdb->get_results( $sql, ARRAY_A );
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Mr. Pace, unfortunately I'm getting a server error 500

Comment: I think the single quotes around `{$now}` were interfering with parsing the PHP.  I modified the answer so we could output the SQL.  Do you have a SQL client that you can use to run queries against the database?

Comment: I do, but how about the global $wpdb, I think it wont work in the client

Comment: I tried this, and it worked, but I removed AND until interval because I don't know how will it work in phpmysql client  

    SELECT p.ID, p.post_title, p.post_name
    FROM  `wp6p_popularpostsdata` AS pps
    INNER JOIN  `wp6p_posts` AS p ON pps.`postid` = p.`ID` 
    WHERE p.post_type =  "post"
    ORDER BY pps.`pageviews` DESC 
    LIMIT 4

Comment: Does that query produce the output you want?

Comment: Almost, I removed  AND pps.last_viewed > DATE_SUB("{$now}", INTERVAL {$interval}) because I'm not sure how to translate the $'s into mysql language

Comment: The `echo` should have output the complete sql with all replacements made.  If you want the database to handle the current date, try this: `DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL {$interval})`.

Comment: tried this: 

1SELECT p.ID, p.post_title, p.post_name
2FROM  `wp6p_popularpostsdata` AS pps
3INNER JOIN  `wp6p_posts` AS p ON pps.`postid` = p.`ID` 
4WHERE p.post_type =  "post"
5AND pps.last_viewed > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL `1 WEEK`)
6ORDER BY pps.`pageviews` DESC 
7LIMIT 4

and got 
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ') ORDER BY pps.`pageviews` DESC LIMIT 4' at line 5

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104543/discussion-between-jeffrey-nerona-and-j-d-pace).